# how to set local path in yaml configuration file in microservice

Tags: config, microservices, netflix-eureka

Here all the properties file are in github location,so that I am able to read using uri path ,how I will read if It's in my local system.Can anybody please guide ?

```
server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: configserver
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://discovery:8761/eureka/

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/****/******
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use spring cloud config in native mode, e.g.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        native:
          search-locations: file:///C:/ConfigData
```

See the following link for more information:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_file_system_backend

Comment: After replacing according to you I am getting this error ,Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentRepository' defined in class org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration$GitRepositoryConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to configure a uri for the git repository .

Comment: If you follow the link in my reply, it states "To use the native profile just launch the Config Server with 'spring.profiles.active=native'". I could reproduce your error by removing this profile, so if you add it, hopefully this will resolve your problem.